# Export to PDF with Chinese languages

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I had a Grid that contain a chinese language. The problem occur when I want to export the data into PDF. It seem appear a weird characters (image below) or something like this . Can anyone help me to solve the issue?

[Here I provide a DEMO in dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/EJUWoNuB)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution, using [kendo.pdf.defineFont](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/pdf/methods/definefont)

1. I need to download [Arial Unicode MS](https://www.wfonts.com/font/arial-unicode-ms) font then place into a folder.
2. By using defineFont I used this code.

```js
<script>
    kendo.pdf.defineFont({
        "Arial Unicode MS"  : " +your url path+ / +font folder location+ "
        //eg. "Arial Unicode MS"  : "myUrl/fonts/arialunicodems.ttf"
    });
</script>
```

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/pdf-export for unicode support you need to use custom fonts. The code which you shared is in online is not loading.