# Chinese characters not exported correctly to PDF using kendo UI

Tags: jquery, unicode, fonts, kendo-ui, export-to-pdf

I am trying to export a div's content which contains Chinese characters using:

```
kendo.drawing.exportPDF()
```

But after exporting to PDF, chinese characters are showing as boxes. I have already tried setting font to unicode approach but no luck. I have also tried 'defineFont' function of kendo using Arial Unicode MS font but still no luck.

Please give inputs on how to properly view exported chinese characters in PDF. Thanks

Comment: Did you search the problem on google or StackOverflow? if so then there will be a lot of answers saying you need to change the font' so it supports Chinese character. Kinda like this code https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/pdf/methods/definefont , but you need to find a font that supports Chinese characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export to PDF with Chinese languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56318953/export-to-pdf-with-chinese-languages)

Comment: i have tried definefont with Arial unicode as well as other approach. But still, chinese characters in exported pdf showing as boxes. Can you suggest anything else?